# Excel comparison with multiple IFs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a scale, based on which I decide the value of the coefficient for the multiplication. The scale looks as following:

[image: Scales]

Which means that:

- for `Category1`: when `value>=1.000.000` then `coef` is `1`, when `value>=500.000` then `coef` is `0.8` and etc.
- Same logic applies for `Category2`;

Then I have input data in the following format:

```
Company !MainCat|Sales Amount|
Company1|T1     |   6.500.000|
Company2|T2     |      70.000|
```

I need to find corresponding coefficient, ratio of the coeffitient and the value `(=ratio*MaxCoef)`. Currently, I am finding coef the following way:
- for company1:

```
 =IF(C8>=$D2;$D$1;IF(C8>=$E2;$E$1;IF(C8>=$F2;$F$1;IF(C8>=$G2;$G$1;IF(C8>=$H2;$H$1;IF(C8>=$I2;$I$1))))))
```

That is literally hardcoded and doesn't look good. Maybe there is a better way of doing ? Any suggestions?

Formula view:

[image: Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `COUNTIF(range, [criteria] < value) * 0.2` as your add `0.2` per `coef` stage.

To you data do: `=COUNTIF(D2:H2, "<"&C8) * 0.2`, count how many stages the value passes `*` the value per stage.

Your count if range needs to be until `H2` as `I2` is `0`, so inferior to `value` and gets counted.

To combine the `COUNTIF()` with a dynamic search for the right category based on `MainCat` you can `MATCH()` the `MainCat` with `Code` which will give the `row` where the `Code` is located and utilize `INDIRECT()` to apply it as `range`.

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B8,B:B,0)&":H"&MATCH(B8,B:B,0)),"<"&C8)*0.2`

`MATCH(B8,B:B,0)` - will match the value on `B8` (lets say `T1`) and return the `row` 2.

`INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B8,B:B,0)&":H"&MATCH(B8,B:B,0)` = `INDIRECT("D"&2&":H"&2)` - will turn the text into an actual `range` to be use by the `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: But, don't you think that every cell in the range is less than `C8` in the first example and the result will be 6. Would it make sense to: `=(COUNTIF(D2:I2, "<"&C8)-1) * 0.2`?

Comment: @tolik I've adjusted the range so it does't include `0` count.

Comment: Saw the edit. But, would it be possible to elaborate in the combination with category?

Comment: @tolik, I've changed the formula to first find the category code and than count if it passes the stages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table ‚Mapping’ that contains two columns, ‚Category’ and ‚Coefficient‘, then use INDEX-MATCH on it as described in https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/.

=INDEX(Mapping[Category]; MATCH([Coefficient]; Mapping[Coefficient]; -1))

This example assumes that you put this formula into a table that has a column named ‚Coefficient‘ with the input value to your multiple IFs.
The trick is that as a match_type argument, provide either -1 or 1, according to your needs.

Comment: I think, that INDEX-MATCH would not be a proper tehcnique to use here. Or, at least, I don't see a right way of usage in this case.

Comment: @tolik well, it can be done or use lookup : horizontally and then vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** do this in VBA. Write your own function which ends in something like that

```
=MyOwnScale(C8; B8; A2:I3)
```

The first parameter of your VBA-function is the value, the second the category and the third is the range with the thresholds. So you can move your cascading `IF`-loops in VBA-Code and you (and your users) see only a clean function call in the cell.