# Scale comparison with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formula that finds the corresponding coefficient `coef` for the given value of a category.

Assume that there is a table in the following form: 
[image: table]
In the table above, the decimals in header (in red) - 1;0.8;0.6;0.4;0.2;0 are the coefficients and `Comparator` is used as a criteria in the `COUNTIF()`.

The formula that is used, in order to find a corresponding `coef` looks as following:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0)&":H"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0));INDIRECT("J"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))&C7)*0,2
```

It works without issues, when I want to get the coef for `Category 1`, but for the `Category 2` it returns the `coef` for the upper boundary. For ex.:
 [image: Example]

As it is noticeable, the `Sales` for the `Company 2` is `75000`, which is between  `5000` and `10000`. The formula returns the value of the `coef` for `10000` -> `0.4`, but should return the `coef` for the `5000` -> `0.6`.

How can I update my formula so that it's able to work for both cases? The only idea that comes to me is to use different formulas, but it seems not right way of doing.

**UPDATE**

With the suggestion from @Miguel_Ryu, have updated formula in the following way:

```
=ABS(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0)&":H"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0));INDIRECT("J"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))&C7)*0,2 - IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))>0;0;1))
```

But still the result is not correct in some cases. Example: 
[image]

As it is noticeable, the result for `Company 2` is still not the desired one. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Hi tolik, it seems to me that you "reversed" the data increments (being that on cat 2) it goes lower with number increase. You can change the formula by adding `=1 - COUNTIF()`.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu thanks for the suggestion, that's something what is clear to me, the problem is that I will have 2 functions in that case. Would it be possible to somehow join them together?

Comment: Yes it is, I'll post an answer in a min

Comment: Seems to me like you just have to put `$`'s in front of your absolute references so that they are unchanged when dragging the formula, e.g. `B1:B3` should be changed to `B$1:B$3`.

Comment: On a side note, your use of `INDIRECT` here (`INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0)&":H"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))`) can and should be replaced by `INDEX`. In this case, can be changed to this formula: `INDEX(D:H;MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0);0)`. `INDIRECT` is volatile (always updating) and `INDEX` is non-volatile (only updates when necessary).

Comment: I agree with @ImaginaryHuman072889, but I'm not currently able to test it. It looks like you'd get the wrong row being returned in your `INDIRECT` functions without using at least partial absolute references. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, thanks for the suggestion. One question: "Does then `D:H` gets the range based on the row returned by match?

Comment: @tolik Yes, `INDEX` is of the form: `INDEX(<range>;<row>;<column>)`. And if `0` is specified for `<row>` or `<column>` then that means you are returning the entire row or column. So you are returning the row # `MATCH(B7;B$1:B$3;0)` (and all of the columns) in the range `D:H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this `IF()` to your formula will check the first value on your `coef` to determine if it starts at `0` or `>0`.

`=IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))>0,0,1)`

Simply add the formula prior to the `COUNTIF()`.

`=IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))>0,0,1) - COUNTIF()`.

P.S.:If you need to check the 1st `coef` vs. 2nd `coef` (e.g.: `Comparator` is decreasing but starts above `0`) use:

`=IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0))>INDIRECT("E"&MATCH(B7;B1:B3;0)),0,1)`

To compare first 2 values on the table.

**Edit:**

@tolik, If you recall on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744181/excel-comparison-with-multiple-ifs) we adjusted the range not to include the `0` `coef`, but now the `coef` on Category 2 is no longer `0`.

To compensate for that you first need to adjust the range from `D:H` to `D:I` and after compensate for the extra `0.2` resulting from the `COUNTIF()`.

Another thing I've noticed is that you change the `Comparator`, which changes the logic of the formula.

This formula will work with a static `Comparator`:

```
=ABS(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B$1:B$3;0)&":I"&MATCH(B7;B$1:B$3;0));"<="&C7)*0.2-IF(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(B7;B$1:B$3;0))>0;0.2;1.2))
```

Notice that I've changed the last `IF` to deduct an extra `0.2` to compensate by the additional range/count.

The `$` are so range doesn't change when dragging the formula to the cell below.

Comment: Doesn't work as it should. 1- I get all the values with "-" , which is clear, due to the `0-countif()`. 2- the coefs doesn't change.

Comment: Didn't think about that ^^, Put the `IF` after the `COUNTIF()`, so `COUNTIF() * 0.2 - IF()` and it won't give negative values.

Comment: in that case - the value for the reversed one is negative ))) Have checked already)

Comment: Anyways, just gonna get the absolute value : `ABS(COUNTIF() * 0.2 - IF())`

Comment: don't think so, since getting a strange value on another example. will update the post in a minute

Comment: Updated  the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165043/discussion-between-tolik-and-miguel-ryu).